# How to write a JOIN statement to combine data from disparate tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following 2 procedures that I use as my source for a report. As of now, I'm presenting 2 different tables in my SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 R2 report, because it doesn't let me put them together as they belong to 2 different data sets.

I want to present them in a single table, but I have not been successful trying to use JOIN here. How do I do that?

NOTE: `cName` in `IAgentQueueStats` corresponds to `UserId` in `AgentActivityLog`.

```
/*** Aggregate values for Call Center Agents for calls, talk and hold time ***/
/*** The detail/row values is per 30-minute interval ***/
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_IAgentQueueStats_OnlyCalls_Grouped]
    @p_StartDate datetime,
    @p_EndDate datetime,
    @p_Agents varchar(8000)
AS

SELECT  [cName]
      ,sum([nAnswered])     SumNAnswered
      ,sum([nAnsweredAcd])  SumNAnsweredAcd
      ,sum([tTalkAcd])      SumTTalkAcd
      ,sum([nHoldAcd])      SumNHoldAcd
      ,sum([tHoldAcd])      SumTHoldAcd
      ,sum([tAcw])          SumTAcw

FROM [I3_IC].[dbo].[IAgentQueueStats]

WHERE dIntervalStart between @p_StartDate and DATEADD(s, 86400-1, @p_EndDate)
  AND CHARINDEX ( cName ,@p_Agents)> 0
  AND cReportGroup <> '*'
  AND cHKey3 = '*' and cHKey4 ='*'
  AND nEnteredAcd > 0
  AND cReportGroup <> 'CCFax Email'
GROUP BY cName
```

And here is the second one:

```
/*** Aggregate values for Call Center Agents for status/activity time ***/
/*** The detail/row values is per start-time/end-time ***/
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_AgentActivity_Grouped]
    @p_StartDate datetime,
    @p_EndDate datetime,
    @p_Agents varchar(8000)
AS

SELECT  [UserId],[StatusCategory],SUM([StateDuration]) [StatusDuration] FROM
(
SELECT   
    [UserId]
    ,[StatusGroup]
    ,[StatusKey]
    , CASE [StatusKey]
        WHEN 'Available'            THEN 'Productive'
        WHEN 'Follow Up'            THEN 'Productive'
        WHEN 'Campaign Call'        THEN 'Productive'
        WHEN 'Awaiting Callback'    THEN 'Productive'
        WHEN 'In a Meeting'         THEN 'Not Your Fault'
        WHEN 'Project Work'         THEN 'Not Your Fault'
        WHEN 'At a Training Session'THEN 'Not Your Fault'
        WHEN 'System Issues'        THEN 'Not Your Fault'
        WHEN 'Test'                 THEN 'Not Your Fault'
        WHEN 'At Lunch'             THEN 'Non Productive'
        WHEN 'Available, Forward'   THEN 'Non Productive'
        WHEN 'Available, Follow-Me' THEN 'Non Productive'
        WHEN 'At Play'              THEN 'Non Productive'
        WHEN 'AcdAgentNotAnswering' THEN 'Non Productive'
        WHEN 'Do Not Disturb'       THEN 'Non Productive'
        WHEN 'Available, No ACD'    THEN 'Non Productive'
        WHEN 'Away from desk'       THEN 'Non Productive'
        ELSE [StatusKey]
    END StatusCategory
     ,stateduration
FROM [I3_IC].[dbo].[AgentActivityLog]
WHERE [StatusDateTime] between @p_StartDate and DATEADD(s, 86400-1, @p_EndDate)
    AND CHARINDEX ( [UserId] ,@p_Agents)> 0
    AND [StatusKey] not in ('Gone Home','Out of the Office','On Vacation','Out of Town')
) a 
GROUP BY [UserId],[StatusCategory]
ORDER BY [UserId], [StatusCategory] desc
```

BTW, if I take some time to comment/reply on your posts, it's not lack of interest, but of understanding...

This is the report I want:
Rows: Person (= `cName` in `IAgentQueueStats` = `UserId` in `AgentActivityLog`)

Columns:
From `IAgentQueueStats`:

```
sum([nAnswered]) 
sum([nAnsweredAcd])
sum([tTalkAcd])
sum([nHoldAcd])
sum([tHoldAcd])
sum([tAcw])
```

From `AgentActivityLog`

The sum of `'Productive'`

The sum of `'Not Your Fault'`

The sum of `'Non Productive'`

But note that `'Productive'`, `'Not Your Fault'` and `'Non Productive'` are values that repeat in rows for `AgentId` which implies many rows with same `AgentId` and value, that have to be totaled and "converted" to a column.

It's complicated, I believe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do it in one SQL statement, so I did it in a few steps, creating temporal tables in the stored procedure so that I could then JOIN the temporal tables and get the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Basic join

```
select IAgentQueueStats.*, AgentActivityLog.* 
from IAgentQueueStats 
join AgentActivityLog 
  on IAgentQueueStats.cName = AgentActivityLog.UserId
```

That is a start.
From there need to know what you want in this combined report.

Try a basic group by

```
select AgentActivityLog.UserId, AgentActivityLog.StatusCategory,SUM(AgentActivityLog.StateDuration),sum(IAgentQueueStats.nAnswered)     
    from IAgentQueueStats 
    join AgentActivityLog 
      on IAgentQueueStats.cName = AgentActivityLog.UserId 
Group By AgentActivityLog.UserId, AgentActivityLog.StatusCategory
```

Since the group by is not the same in the reports not clear how to do this.
One is like the above.
The other is you split it up into two group by and then join that result.
Until you define the report cannot know which.

Comment: I think I can manage the WHERE clause, but not the GROUP BY. BTW, you mean AgentActivityLog.UserId.

Comment: I will try that. Will get back to you.

Comment: It's not working. For example: before the JOIN, the Sum(nAnswered) for a certain user and date is 17. After the JOIN, the value is 808,809.The reason is not only that the filter in the WHERE clause is not being evaluated but the JOIN is kind of multiplying the records.

Comment: As I said before until you define what you want cannot help.